# KNN error:Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , all.vars(Terms), drop = FALSE) : undefined columns selected

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

Iam using education dataset US

when i use KNN without tuning i got the output as right

```
knnmodel=knn(train = train_scaled[,-c(1,4:8)],test = test_scaled[,-c(1,4:8)],
             cl =as.factor(train_scaled$admit),k=3,prob = T)
knnpred=knnmodel
tab7=table(actual=test_scaled$admit,predicted=knnpred)`
cm_knn=confusionMatrix(tab7)
cm_knn$byClass
```

But with tuning i got the error

> undefined columns selected

```
HypKnn=train(as.factor(train_scaled$admit)~.,data = train_scaled[,-c(1,4:8)],method="knn")
```

-c(1,4:8) its just i deleted the categorical variables

****Iam using library Class for knn and caret for train tuning****

str(train_scaled)

```
'data.frame':   250 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ admit      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ gre        : num [1:250, 1] -1.778 0.637 1.844 -0.571 -1.605 ...
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 2.86e-17
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 1
 $ gpa        : num  3.61 3.67 4 2.93 3.08 3.39 3.92 4 4 3.44 ...
 $ ses        : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 2 3 2 1 1 1 3 3 ...
 $ Gender_Male: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ Race       : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 3 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ rank       : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 3 3 1 4 2 3 2 4 1 3 ...
 $ categGPA   : Factor w/ 1 level "Low": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>
```

Comment: Please indicate the packages that you are using, ideally in your code blocks. I can think of 5 packages off the top of my head that have `knn` functions. Also, and idea of what your data looks like would be helpful. Perhaps as simple as results from `str(train_scaled)`

Comment: yep, i edited my question above